# Mp4 file not playing on Ipad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, html

I need to convert a bunch of mp4 files so they are playable on Ipad. I already succesfully encoded a mp4 file so it plays on all major browser ( IE,Firefox,Chrome, Safari) the mp4 file even plays on my android 4.x device.

The only 2 devices it wont play on are Ipad and iPhone. I'm using Handbrake 4 to convert the files using the ipad/iphone presets but it just wont work. Can someone explain to me why the file with the following charactaristics wont work on all except iOS devics?

```
General
Complete name                            : chapter4.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 10.4 MiB
Duration                                 : 2mn 56s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 492 Kbps
Movie name                               : Chapter 4
Performer                                : Acuity
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-02-06 16:04:37
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-02-06 16:06:28
Writing application                      : HandBrake 0.9.8 2012071700

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2mn 56s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 179 Kbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 400 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.030 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.021
Stream size                              : 3.76 MiB (36%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 120
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=2 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=umh / subme=6 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=300 / keyint_min=30 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=3 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-02-06 16:04:37
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-02-06 16:06:28
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2mn 56s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 85.2 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 191 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 1.80 MiB (17%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-02-06 16:04:37
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-02-06 16:06:26

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : ac-3
Duration                                 : 2mn 56s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 224 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.72 MiB (46%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-02-06 16:04:37
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-02-06 16:06:26
```

To play the video i'm using a combination of flash and video tag. Using modernizr.js i'd figure out of the h264 standard is supported. And If it is the following tag is displayed:

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="" preload="auto" width="700" height="420" poster="http://server/video_first_frame.png" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://server/9BF315E824517C75C1257B090055B87A/$File/Chapter 4.mp4">
</video>
```

When viewing on the ipad I can see it displays the html5 video tag but it displays as it can not understand the file. Another file in the same application ( ocean.mp4 from the video.js website) is playing correctly so I suspect it has something to do with the encoding..

Comment: Will it play in the Movies app on iPad?

Comment: A really wide shot: What happens if you replace the space in the filename with %20 (or omit it altogether and rename the file accordingly)?

Comment: bassplayer7 As stated in the title it wont play on ipad or iphone at all

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Apple media players try to play all "enabled" audio tracks simultaneously. The iPhone (and possibly iPad) cannot play AC-3 audio.  There are two things you can try. 1) Use Subler to disable the second (AC-3) audio track, 2) Use MP4Tools to remove the second (AC-3) audio track.